# How to compare time in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, datetimepicker, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies

here I want to validate time. as per this image, when I choose the Shift Begin time and End Time then whenever I am choosing break time it will always between Shift begin time and Shift end time.

Here is the Image of output

[image]

Here is the code for the time picker

```
                       DateTimeField( 
                          decoration: InputDecoration(
                            contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                                vertical: 15.0, horizontal: 10),
                            labelText: "Time",
                            filled: true,
                            fillColor: Colors.white,
                            border: OutlineInputBorder(
                              borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(6),
                            ),
                          ),
                          format: format,
                          onShowPicker: (context, currentValue) async {
                            final time = await showTimePicker(
                              context: context,
                              initialTime: TimeOfDay.fromDateTime(
                                currentValue ?? DateTime.now(),
                              ),
                            );
                            return DateTimeField.convert(time);
                          },
                        ),
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54639993/dart-flutter-how-to-compare-two-timeofday-times

Comment: @JayVasant It's not Flutter's ways.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
  static var startShift = DateTime.now();   
  final endShift = DateTime.now().add(Duration(hours: 8));   
  static var startBreak = startShift.add(Duration(hours: 3));   
  final endBreak = startBreak.add(Duration(hours: 1));

if ((startBreak.isAfter(startShift) && startBreak.isBefore(endShift)) &&
    (endBreak.isAfter(startShift) && endBreak.isBefore(endShift))) {
  //--- Break is within a shift.
} else {
  //--- Invalid break;
}
```

Comment: interesting answer wait I'll try and then let you know

Comment: Here I am selecting the time from DatetimeFormField so how can I define the time for that. because the user can select anything from time picker and shift is not may exact 8 hours it may also change.

Comment: What kind of exception? can you share?

Comment: it okay it just a static member problem

Comment: @RutvikGumasana does this solve your problem?? If yes, please mark it as the correct answer. 

Comment: Yes buddy sure but before please check edit i have suggested.

Comment: @RutvikGumasana Approved.