# Find difference between to times in TimeOfDay class like (10:50 - 08:00 = 02:50 )

Tags: datetime, flutter, dart, timeofday

I should have two times, one is the current time and the other I get it from time picker as shown below.

How can I get the difference between them?

[image: Code]

Comment: can you add some more details mean from some raw input to expected output.

Comment: Please add your code as characters. To post it as an image doesn't make any sense.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54639993/dart-flutter-how-to-compare-two-timeofday-times This might help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use either of these two.

```
int getMinutesDiff(TimeOfDay tod1, TimeOfDay tod2) {
  return (tod1.hour * 60 + tod1.minute) - (tod2.hour * 60 + tod2.minute);
}

TimeOfDay getTimeOfDayDiff(TimeOfDay tod1, TimeOfDay tod2) {
  var minutes = (tod1.hour * 60 + tod1.minute) - (tod2.hour * 60 + tod2.minute);

  return TimeOfDay(hour: minutes ~/ 60, minute: minutes % 60);
}
```

Comment: Be aware that the difference between two times can depend on the date if you're in a place that observes daylight saving time.